# Why my C# Project properties has no target framework and no combo box choices?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, project, avalondock

I downloaded AvalonDock from GitHub and I open in in Visual Studio.
There is no "Target framework" and the ComboBox list is empty and the ComboBox is disabled.

Anybody know why?

Note: I have a .net Core WPF application and add AvalonDock project as a dependency and everything works well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is most likely because of Multi-Targets.

Open the project in Notepad, or Visual Studio by right clicking the Project name, and selecting 'Edit Project File' (if available), and look for a line like this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

Here is more information from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Unfortunately, there is no Gui way to Multi-target, so that is why you will not see a target framework in your project.

Comment: Thanks !!! <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;net4</TargetFrameworks>  Seems that you got it. I hope Microsoft will soon update Visual Studio to takes those cases into account.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree on the GUI, but with the price of Visual Studio and Nuget and Git Hub and SQL Server, I change my complaints to thank you Microsoft.

Comment: I work with Microsoft product for 25 years now. I like Microsoft. But a lot less than 10 years ago. I have to code something now and feel that I'm in a big conversion where everything is working soso. We have great frameworks like UWP, WPF and Core but it is actually no really easy to manage all of that if ever possible. They silently disengaged themself from desktop dev since ~2010. They now seems to invest in Core but how can we know what will be supported and when (Win2D, SVG, ...) ? Why they don't do their softwares in C#? How can they say "Adopt C#" but they do not use it themself?